# What are different Mathematical concepts which can be introduced to 12-16 year students in an activity based way

Tags: secondary-education, mathematics-in-daily-life, recreational-learning

Activities are a great way to engage students with Mathematics. And that also helps them to visualise mathematical facts. For example, Pi in its decimal form appears to have no pattern (we used to say). But, if we ask students to colour code digits (upto some 500 or 600), they will automatically be able to see that.

If we allow students to play with periodicity of repeating decimals after a while they will figure out Midy's property. [https://web.iitd.ac.in/~atripath/publications/Midy.pdf](https://web.iitd.ac.in/%7Eatripath/publications/Midy.pdf)

So, what all other concepts can help students to get engaged while having fun.

Comment: *Pi in its decimal form is having no pattern* --- It's probably not a good idea to use imprecise wording like this when discussing mathematics with students. What you mean to say (but NOT what you actually said) is "Pi in its decimal form appears to have no pattern". Besides not being misleading (even incorrect), this more correct wording also motivates possibly intellectually instructive discussions, such as whether Pi can have a pattern even if it doesn't appear to have a pattern. That said, the color coding of the digits of Pi is a nice idea.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Thanks for pointing out that. I have edited that part in question. You are correct - write wording can invoke much thoughtful discussion.

Comment: How about introducing fractals?